# Maven build is not picking up new changes which i make to source files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat7

Maven build is not picking up new changes which i make to source files. Why does this this happen? I am trying to build from eclipse.

Comment: Please add more details like what your pom.xml looks like and what exactly you are trying (maven goal) to build the code

Comment: check if you are building your project from right directory ( in case of duplicate projects)

Comment: Did you save your changes?

Comment: There are no duplicate projects.  and yes i am building from right directory @ Gaur93.

Comment: I am very much sure that i have hit ctrl+s more that hundred times!

Answer (score 0):

Use update setting in eclipse.[image]

Comment: I tried changing maven setting. I still don't see updated source being reflected in war.